# ruby multiple regexp gsub with array.inject

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have to work with a long text and make some substitution with regexp inside it.
Now I wrote the following code:

````
text = File.read(file)
replacements = [
                [/```([\w]+)/, "\n\1>"],
                [/```\n/, "\n\n"],
                [/pattern not found/, 'sub'],
                [/pattern that should be found/, 'no sub'],
               ]
replacements.inject(text) do |text, (k,v)|
    if text =~ k
        text.gsub!(k,v)
    end
end
File.write(name', text)
````

If every regexp is found in my document everything works fine, but if a replacements pattern is not found, **all subsequent replacements are not carried out**.

I put the `if text =~ k` but it does not work the same.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that [`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) returns `nil` if there were no substitutions made, and the result if there were. Another glitch is that you call matching twice, the check for `text =~ k` is redundant.

I would go with *not inplace* version of `gsub`:

```
result = replacements.inject(text) do |text, (k, v)|
  text.gsub(k, v)
end
```

the above should do the trick.

Whether you still want to use inplace substitution, you might just return `text` itself on unsuccessful `gsub!`:

```
result = replacements.inject(text) do |text, (k, v)|
  text.gsub!(k, v) || text
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The block of `inject` must return `memo` value. So, you may have to change your code to do this:

```
replacements.inject(text) do |text, (k,v)|
    text.gsub(k,v)
end
```

When `if test =~ k` failed in your case, the block's output was `nil` - hence, the issue.

---

Alternatively, you can use `with_object`

```
replacements.each.with_object(text) do |(k,v), text|
    text.gsub!(k,v)
end
```

Comment: `with_object` has an opposite parameters order: `|(k, v), text|`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks, will fix it

Comment: You don't need the conditioning. That is some meaningless thing that the OP put.

Comment: @sawa  Arigatou gozaimasu !!  Did some updates based on your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Each inject iteration should return memo (in your case `text`) to the next iteration. Try this code:

```
replacements.inject(text) do |text, (k,v)|
  if text =~ k
    text.gsub!(k,v)
  end
  text
end
```